# Why does the word delight have positive connotations?

Tags: etymology

I'm sitting here, and hear someone respond to a request with "I'd be delighted". I understand the words to say this is a positive response along the lines of "sure, I'd be happy to help".

But I'm confused right now. When I look at the word, my mind breaks it up into de-light. And to me, that doesn't seem like a positive thing.

Hoping someone can shed some light on this for me (ha).

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ELU. Do you have the same problem with *delicious and delectable*? They all come from the same root word: c.1200, Old French *delit* from *delitier* (please greatly). This is where a good dictionary helps. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. See [List of general references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/). Please take a few minutes to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how to use this site.

Comment: One of the joys of English is that many words can essentially be "parsed" incorrectly, to produce contradictory meanings.  English is a punster's delight, and the de-light of dour soreheads.

Comment: When I looked delight up at dictionary.com, it provided nothing that would answer my question. Sure, maybe some dictionaries will answer my question, but I thought that was "enough" to make this a question here. Apparently not.

Answer (score 2):

Reference OED:

---

Noun-

The etymological delite is found as late as 1590, but earlier in 16th c. it had generally been supplanted by delight, an erroneous spelling after light, flight, etc.

Verb-

The current erroneous spelling after light, etc. arose in the 16th c., and prevailed about 1575: the Bible of 1611 occasionally retained delite.

Answer (score 0):

In some words, the initial letters **de** connotates "undo," for example "accelerate" and de-accelerate."  In other cases,  the two words are total unrelated:

*You can light a candle, but you cannot delight it.  You must extinguish it.*

Comment: Well, you *could* delight the candle, but in those cases where the prefixed version exists as a separate word, it's pretty common to use a hyphen and in speech will normally get an extra stress on the prefix.  Return vs re-turn, (p)reserve vs (p)re-serve, etc.

Comment: @guifa Your points are well taken.

Comment: This all reminds me of the schoolboy who was asked by his teacher  to put the words *delight*, *depot* and *defender* into a sentence. After scratching his head he  said 'De light was out, de pot was gone, so I did it in de fender'. The joke 'has whiskers on it' and dates from my own schooldays when people still had open fires, and used chamber pots.

Comment: @WS2  Similar to the remark that Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart spent the last 30 years of his life *composing* and the next 222 years *decomposing.*

Comment: @Gary'sStudent In my day the joke was that an Austrian farmer uncovered Mozart's grave and asked him why he was furiously erasing an immense stack of musical manuscripts ...